# I encountered some issues simulating the shape transition of silicon clusters using LAMMPS

Tags: computational-physics, simulation, molecular-dynamics, density-functional-theory, lammps

==

I have been trying to write an input file for [lammps](/questions/tagged/lammps) to simulate the shape transition of a nanoparticle of silicon using multiple potentials to obtain the best structure, which I will compare with a [density-functional-theory](/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory) simulation results. However, I have encountered an issue with the structure of the nanoparticle being distorted from the beginning when using the `fix ID nve` command, and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried to change the `fix nve` command with the `fix nvt` command or just leaving the `velocity` command running alone, but the resulting structure is not as expected when compared to the [density-functional-theory](/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory) results.

Her is the input file that i have been using:

```
variable        dt equal 0.001
units           metal

variable t equal 300
variable t_start equal 300
variable t_final equal 1

# ----------------  Loop start -------------------------------------
variable i loop 12 26
variable cluster equal $i
variable epair_cluster equal epair/v_cluster
variable num_steps equal (${t}-${t_final})*1000

#-----------------------ATOM DEFINITION----------------------------
read_data       data/si_${i}.data 
mass            1 28.085  ##Silicon

#------------------------FORCE FIELDS------------------------------
#pair_style      sw
#pair_coeff      * * Si.sw Si

#pair_style edip
#pair_coeff * * Si.edip Si

pair_style tersoff
pair_coeff * * Si.tersoff Si

#pair_style     tersoff/mod/c 
#pair_coeff * * Si.tersoff.modc Si

neighbor        2 bin
neigh_modify    every 10 delay 0 check no

thermo_style custom step temp v_epair_cluster etotal v_cluster
thermo          1000

#dump            0 all xyz 100 min/si_min_$i.xyz
#dump_modify     0 flush yes
#dump_modify     0 sort id element Si
#minimize 1.0e-4 1.0e-6 100 1000
#undump          0

reset_timestep  0
timestep        $(dt)

#------------------------------ Setting the velocities  -------------------------
fix         1 all nve 
velocity        all create  ${t_start} 4928459 rot yes dist gaussian

dump            5 all xyz 1000 si_$i_$t.xyz
dump_modify     5 append yes

run     250000

unfix       1
#------------------------------- annealing -------------------------
fix             1 all nvt temp ${t_start} ${t} 0.1

dump            1 all xyz 1000 si_$i_$t.xyz
dump_modify     1 append yes

run             ${num_steps}

#------------------------------- Relaxation  -------------------------
fix             2 all nvt temp  ${t} ${t} 0.1

dump            2 all xyz 1000 si_$i_$t.xyz
dump_modify     2 append yes

run             250000

#-------------------------------  couling -------------------------
fix             4 all temp/berendsen ${t} ${t_final} 0.1


dump           3 all xyz 1000 si_$i_$t.xyz
dump_modify    3 append yes

run             ${num_steps}

#------------------------------- Relaxation -----------------------
fix     5 all nvt temp ${t_final} ${t_final} 0.1

dump           4 all xyz 1000 si_$i_$t.xyz
dump_modify    4 append yes

run            250000

 clear
 next i
 jump annealing_si_loop.lmp

print         "Simulation complete"
```

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer in the Matter Modelling forum

Comment: I can migrate the question to Matter Modelling, if you are fine with it.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion,but i'm trying to solve the problem with lammps.

Comment: Lamps is a matter modelling code. There are many more lammps experts on the matter modelling forum

Comment: Thank you for the information